# jasmine testing service ionic 2 app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jasmine, ionic2

I'm new in Jasmine and I'm trying to test my ionic 2 service with Jasmine.

My service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {User} from '../Entity/user';
import {SecureStorageServices} from '../Providers/secureStorageServices';

@Injectable()

export class myService {

    constructor(private secureStorageServices: SecureStorageServices, private user: User) {
    }
//Some other methods which I want to unit test.
```

I have to services in my constructor.

I tried to do:

```
describe('Service: my Service', () => {


it('should do xxx', () => {
    let service = new myService();

      expect(service).toBeDefined();
});
```

Problem: my new service has no parameter and do not work.

Do you know what I'm missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your service using a TestBed which will hold the relevant imports. Because you need to somehow inject the parameters in to your constructor.

So it should go like this:

```
 describe('Service: my Service', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [
      ],
      providers: [
        SecureStorageServices, // all related providers here
        User,
        myService 
      ]
    })
  }));

   it('should do xxx', inject([myService], (service) => {
       expect(service).toBeDefined();
    }));
 });
```